# Circuit identification/functionality: Mercedes-Benz start-stop button (MB part no: A2139055500)

Tags: pcb, automotive, reverse-engineering

As a first PCB reverse-engineering project trying to understand the logic/function of Mercedes-Benz start-stop button. Mercedes-Benz part no: A2139055500.
Did my best to draw it up in EasyEDA as I understood it. Wasn't confident to share the project with a link because of the licensing issue as it's reverse engineered. So I'm sharing a screenshot.

[image: EasyEDA circuit]
[image: PCB front and back]

**So far I have identified:**

1. Pin 1 is common ground.
2. Pin 3 is switched to ground with switch "SW1".
3. Pin 5 is positive and switches LED on through a dropdown resistor R1 (22 Ω).
4. The LED on the board is 6 legged Osram white LED (LUW GVCP-FAGA-GMKM-24E4), but only 2 pins are actually used - 5 (common anode / GND) and 6 (cathode).
5. SMD capacitors C1 & C2 are both 0.83 nF.

**Questions:**

1. What components are the 2 SOT-23 3 legged SMDs? 1 has markings "5C F" and "A1W 87". The component codes on the EasyEDA drawing are not correct. Placed a first 3 legged SOT-23 component.
2. What  the whole pin 2,4 and the switch "SW2" logic is supposed to implement?

All help and advice is much appreciated!

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Statements 2 and 3 don't match what the schematic shows. If the schematic is correct pin 3 should be positive with respect to pin 5 and SW1 connects the LED and resistor between them. Positive voltage from pin 3  would go through SW1 to the anode of the LED, the cathode of the LED goes through the resistor to pin 5.

Comment: Looking at the boards it appears that the schematic is incorrect, but I can't see them well enough to be sure of all of the connections.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for helping to improve the post!

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks for having a look! You are correct, I had made a mistake rewiring after moving components around. I double checked the 1 & 3, also pin 5. Now it should reflect the schematic. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! Please redraw the schematic with the LED as an LED, all positive voltages pointing up and negative pointing down. Assume pin 5 is positive Vcc. Probe out where the vias from pin 5 net go.

Comment: Pin 1 can't be GND if your drawing of LED is correct. Pin A clearly needs +. In general, to make it more readable, try to align components vertically when drawing schematics. With current flowing top-to-bottom (so GND on the lower part)

Comment: @winny Thanks for the feedback. Will consider your suggestions. One thing tho, took the 6 leg LED as a component, also have the internals of it drawn on the bottom right corner. So from correctness pont, I think using the component is correct, but you are correct that I could just use 1 LED symbol as actually only 2 legs of the 6 are used.

Comment: PCB footprint != schematic symbol. The schematic is supposed to be human readable. Your eCAD won’t care about anything but the net list anyway.

Comment: @floppydisk Thanks for the feedback! When it comes to the drawing of LED, I think the separate component drawing on the bottom right, it's correct. I just drew the internals of the LED shown on the schematic.
When it comes to the top to bottom, this means I give up on real world component placement (pins being in a row). BUT, I guess it makes sense for readability, most automotive schematics are as you say - current flows top to bottom.

Comment: OK, so @winny and floppydisk reflect that I should be making a schematic. Is EasyEDA good for that if things are placed correctly or you suggest something else? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Click on edit and then the schematic symbol. A rather full-fledged schematic editor will open.

Comment: Thanks @winny, will do with CircuitLAB. The 3 legged SMD identification is still a challenge, but I will try some more Googling.